# AuthenticationManager.authenticate fails even if UserDetailsManager.loadUserByUsername returns non-null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to use UserDetailsManager to create a user and AuthenticationManager to authenticate a user in my SpringBoot application.
Configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

}

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
```

Controller

```java
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityList = List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));

    @PostMapping("/login")
    ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> login(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest form) {

        try {
            var user = userDetailsManager.loadUserByUsername(form.username()); // Not null, valid user
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(form.username(), form.password(), this.grantedAuthorityList)
            ); // throws AuthenticationException
             ...

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
    }
}
```

The user was created using this before

```java
userDetailsManager.createUser(new User(form.username(), form.password(), this.grantedAuthorityList));
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This problem is userDetailsManager and authenticationManager used different password encoder. Change public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() to use the injected password encoder

Comment: Also create user with userDetailsManager.createUser(new User(username, passwordEncoder.encode(password), this.grantedAuthorityList));